Why my Option account is required when invoke from js client?
all.
I am trying to use Option account in a demo, where, token related accounts are optional, when not provided, it will transfer SOL from my contract to user, other wise transfer SPL token to user.

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransTokenOut<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,  // 

    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: SystemAccount<'info>,  // i.e. the user who receive the token.

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"vault".as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub sol_vault: SystemAccount<'info>, //the PDA account use to store coin.

    #[account(
        mut,
        associated_token::mint = mapping_token_mint,
        associated_token::authority = user
    )]
    pub user_token_account: Option<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,  // user token account

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        associated_token::mint = mapping_token_mint,
        associated_token::authority = sol_vault
    )]
    pub token_vault: Option<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,

    #[account(
        mut,
    )]
    pub mapping_token_mint: Option<Account<'info, Mint>>,    

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

But it raise error whenever I provide with null .
transfer SOL error:  AnchorError: AnchorError caused by account: mapping_token_mint. Error Code: ConstraintAccountIsNone. Error Number: 2020. Error Message: A required account for the constraint is None.
    at Function.parse (/opt/test/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:167:14)
    at translateError (/opt/test/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:276:35)
    at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (/opt/test/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:35:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errorLogs: [
    'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: mapping_token_mint. Error Code: ConstraintAccountIsNone. Error Number: 2020. Error Message: A required account for the constraint is None.'
  ],
  logs: [
    'Program Bj6ubFUkcvTTohw29YcTLSYi7r22mHftgAuSrzSZPtBJ invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: transferSplOut',
    'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: mapping_token_mint. Error Code: ConstraintAccountIsNone. Error Number: 2020. Error Message: A required account for the constraint is None.',
    'Program Bj6ubFUkcvTTohw29YcTLSYi7r22mHftgAuSrzSZPtBJ consumed 12744 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program Bj6ubFUkcvTTohw29YcTLSYi7r22mHftgAuSrzSZPtBJ failed: custom program error: 0x7e4'
  ],
  error: {
    errorCode: { code: 'ConstraintAccountIsNone', number: 2020 },
    errorMessage: 'A required account for the constraint is None',
    comparedValues: undefined,
    origin: 'mapping_token_mint'
  },

====================== Edit2:
my js client code is:
        txHash = await program.methods
            .transTokenOut(amount, fee)
            .accounts({
                signer: g_player,
                user: g_player2,
                solVault: solVaultPDA,
                userTokenAccount: null,   
                tokenVault: null,
                mappingTokenMint: null, // will fail.  
            })
            .rpc();

Note: null value for userTokenAccount and tokenVault work well, but null for mappingTokenMint will got the error as described above.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Could you please share the client code you're using to build the transaction?
In Anchor, optional accounts aren't truly optional. If an optional account isn't provided, the Anchor client automatically passes the current program ID. The on-chain program will then check if the account passed is equal to the program ID, and if so, it will treat the account as None.

You might wonder why the Anchor client passes the current program ID instead of the System Program or another public key. The reason is that the program's public key is already included in the transaction since you're calling it. This approach doesn't significantly affect the transaction size, whereas using a different public key would consume 32 bytes unnecessarily (if it's not already used in the transaction).

txHash = await program.methods
.transTokenOut(amount, fee)
.accounts({
signer: g_player,
user: g_player2,
solVault: solVaultPDA,
userTokenAccount: null,
tokenVault: null,
mappingTokenMint: null,
})
.rpc();
Note: null value for userTokenAccount and tokenVault work, but null for mappingTokenMint will got the error as described above.

yes, I understand the mechanism in the background. And I was sure there is ' "isOptional": true' for mappingTokenMint account in the IDL file

@breezewang You client code looks correct to me and I cannot reproduce the error. Can you try on your side on the following solpg project: https://beta.solpg.io/66d46f76cffcf4b13384d328.

hi, CanardMandrain.  I run test of your demo project, all goes well.
For my case, I doubt that it is the bug of "@coral-xyz/anchor" package, because when I provide mappingTokenMint with program.programId, invoke success. I use 'anchor run' to execute the script.
